# Why am i getting an EOFerror at input().split()?

Tags: python

Why am i getting an EOFerror at `input().split()`?

```
teams = {}

count = 0

n = int(input())

while (count < n):
    t1, t2, p1, p2 = input().split()

    p1 = int(p1)
    p2 = int(p2)


    if (t1 not in teams):
        teams[t1] = 0

    if (t2 not in teams):
        teams[t2] = 0

    #if home team wins
    if (p1 > p2):
        teams[t1] += (p1 + 3000)
        teams[t2] += (p2 + 50)

    #if away team wins
    if (p1 < p2):
        teams[t1] += (p1 + 50)
        teams[t2] += (p2 + 3500)

    #if teams draw
    if (p1 == p2):
            teams[t1] += (p1 + 1000)
            teams[t2] += (p2 + 1000)

count += 1          


print(max(teams, keys=teams.get)) 

print(min(teams, keys=teams.get))
```

Comment: What is the input you type into your console? And can you post  the exact stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

Incrementing `count` is done outside the loop, so it remains 0 all the time inside the loop, so you keep reading too far.

Indent the statement so it lies under the `while`.

Comment: Debugging hint: use `print` statements to output interesting values during the execution. I didn't look too closely at the code, but printing `value` told me that it stayed at 0.